# Creating database in Entity Framework Code first migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

In my project I have two separate DbContext's. For one project I have migration configuration and for another I don't have - it just create database automatically.

Now I would like to create application that use DbMigrator and remove all structurs from database and create it in empty database. There is my code:

```
public void Install(DatabaseDeployment databaseDeployment)
{
    var migrators = new List<DbMigrator>();
    migrators.Add(this.GetMigrator<DbContext1>(databaseDeployment.ConnectionString));
    migrators.Add(this.GetMigrator<DbContext2>(databaseDeployment.ConnectionString));
    migrators.ForEach(x => x.Update("0"));
    migrators.ForEach(x => x.Update());
}

private DbMigrator GetMigrator<TDbContext>(string connectionString) where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    var configuration = this.FindMigrationsConfiguration<TDbContext>();
    configuration.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
    var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
    return migrator;
}

private DbMigrationsConfiguration<TDbContext> FindMigrationsConfiguration<TDbContext>() where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    var configurationType =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(type => typeof(DbMigrationsConfiguration<TDbContext>).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    if (configurationType != null)
    {
        return (DbMigrationsConfiguration<TDbContext>)Activator.CreateInstance(configurationType);
    }
    else
    {
        return new DbMigrationsConfiguration<TDbContext> { AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true };
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Second Update call throw the following SqlException:

```
Additional information: There is already an object named '__MigrationHistory' in the database.
```

It's look like Entity Framework is trying to create that table dispate it already exist. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which EF and EF Provider are you using? In 6.1 (6.1.0 or 6.1.1 or 6.1.2)something changed about checking if the __MigrationHistory exists (now the table existence check is made with a service on the EF Provider, before it was checked with a "select ... from __MigrationHistory" query directly from the EF Framework). For sure it works, __MigrationHistory can have more rows one per context. To understand what's wrong you can also activate the profiler for your DBMS (if it has one)

Comment: I'm using the latest version: EF 6.1.3

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Provider or another Server/Provider?

Comment: Yes, I'm using standard SQL Server Provider (System.Data.SqlClient). I just checked in profiler and EF doesn't check if __MigrationHistory arleady exists